# standby command on cisco 3650-24ps not found packet tracer

Tags: cisco

I'm currently trying to build a small network with two 3650-24ps Multilayer switches at the distribution level in packet tracer.

I want to enable HSRP and configure a virtual default gateway interface at 172.16.100.1 for both Multilayer switches, but when I enter the interface on one of the Multilayer switches and type `standby ?`, it says `% Unrecognized command`.

I looked up a tutorial video, and the person is using the same 3650-24ps Multilayer switch but on his switch the command is working. What do I need to do to get the standby command on my 3650-24ps Multilayer switch?

Answer (score 0):

would be good to see what you have already configured in the packet tracer.
where do you run this standby command, you know you have to run it on a vlan interface and not a physical interface ?

Also packet tracer is not really a suitable app to use for training.
Consider using GNS3.

Answer (score 0):

Late response.

When you directly go the interface and try the `standby` command as the OP did, you get the error message.

```
Switch(config)#int g1/0/1
Switch(config-if)#standby ?
% Unrecognized command
```

This is because the port is a layer 2 port. One must change it to a layer 3 port by using `no switchport`. Then, try the `standby` command again. There won't be any error.

```
Switch(config-if)#no switchport 
Switch(config-if)#standby ?
  <0-4095>  group number
  ip        Enable HSRP and set the virtual IP address
  ipv6      Enable HSRP IPv6
  preempt   Overthrow lower priority Active routers
  priority  Priority level
  timers    Hello and hold timers
  track     Priority Tracking
  version   HSRP version
```